# Prove that if $E[X_1^p]<\infty$, then $\frac{\max_{1\le i\le n} X_i}{n^{1/p}} \rightarrow 0$ in probability where $\{X_n\}$ is i.i.d and non-negative

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose $\{X_n\}_{n\geq 1}$ are iid and non negative. Define $M_n=\max \limits_{i=1,\ldots,n}\{X_i\}.$

**Prove if $E[X_1^p]<\infty$, then $\frac{M_n}{n^{1/p}}\rightarrow 0$ in probability.**

As a previous result I have that $P[M_n>x]\leq nP[X_1>x].$ Is this result useful to prove this convergence? I would appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $Y_i=X_i^{p}$. Then $(Y_i)$ is i.i.d with finite mean. By SLLN $\frac {S_n} n \to EY_1$ almost surely where $S_n=Y_1+Y_2+...+Y_n$. Now $\frac {Y_n} n=\frac {S_n-S_{n-1}} n=\frac {S_n} n-\frac {n-1}n\frac {S_{n-1}} {n-1} \to EY_1-EY_1=0$ almost surely.

It is an  elementary fact that if $\frac  {x_n} n \to 0$ then $\frac {\max {\{x_1,x_2,..,x_n\}}} n \to 0$ also.

We have proved that $\frac {M_n^{p}} n \to 0$ which implies $\frac {M_n} {n^{1/p}} \to 0$ almost surely. Of course almost sure convergence implies  convergence in probability.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the result $P[M_n>x]\leq nP[X_1>x]$. Observe that

$$P[M_n/n^{1/p}>\epsilon]=P[M_n>\epsilon n^{1/p}]
\le nP[X>\epsilon n^{1/p}]=nP[X^p>\epsilon^pn].$$ Now use the inequality $P[Y>a]\le E\left[\frac YaI(Y>a)\right]$ to conclude $$nP[X^p>\epsilon^pn]\le E\left[\frac{X^p}{\epsilon^p}I(X^p>\epsilon^pn)\right],$$ and finally argue that the RHS tends to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.